# Laravel eloquent models with many to many relationship, without integer keys

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot

Primary keys defined in my tables are UUID. When I define many to many relationship and try to sync related records I get error which shows:

```
insert into "productoption" ("optionid", "productid") values (d359a612-5169-4c0d-a7d7-9d1c4f8dda9f, 732a9cb3-d14f-4343-9d0c-3794b58f2f6f))
```

As you can see UUID values are not quoted which throws exception from PostgreSQL.

In my models I have:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

This helps to hint Eloquent that model key is not integer and must be handled differently. Because pivot table doesn't have its own model I don't know how to tell Eloquent that keys used to join tables are not integers.

What is the best way to solve it?

I use:

- Laravel 5.1
- PHP 5.6
- PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like the following when declaring the relationship method in your models:

```
// Product.php
protected $primaryKey = 'product_uuid';
public function options()
{
    return $this
           ->belongsToMany('App\Option', 'product_option', 'product_uuid', 'option_uuid');
}

// Option.php
protected $primaryKey = 'option_uuid';
public function products()
{
    return $this
           ->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_option', 'option_uuid', 'product_uuid');
}
```

Differentiate promary key names in both tables, use (`product_uuid` and `option_uuid`) otherwise you'll fall in more trouble.